# Persistent data in my android app is getting lost when I open it again 30 mins later

Tags: java, android

While viewing this activity I'll hit the home button on my phone to take me to my phone's home screen. When I reopen the app 30+ mins later the string below doesn't print out the player's turn that I saw on the screen 30+ mins beforehand, instead it prints out "Player 0's turn" which is not a valid player number for my app. This leads me to believe its not getting that whose_turn data from the GlobalClass that I store my data in when I reopen app.

```
private int whose_turn;
private TextView tv1;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_screen);

    tv1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.game_msg);      

    whose_turn = GlobalClass.whoseturn;

    tv1.setText("Player " + Integer.toString(whose_turn) + "'s Turn");

}
```

I'm sure it has something to do with the activity's life cycle but I'm not certain what stages it's going through during those 30+ mins or how to make sure it displays the right data.

Can someone tell me what's going on here?  I've tried reading the documentation relevant to this issue and some other experimental solutions using savedInstanceState but I've had no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing `GlobalClass` is a `static` class. This will be lost when the class loader is destroyed. If you want it to be truly persistent then the best place for something like this is `SharedPreferences`. Here you can store simple data and retrieve it at any time. You can't be guaranteed that `static` class variables will be available when you need them.

The [SharedPreferences Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) have a really good example of getting started with saving and retrieving them.

[Full SharedPreferences Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

[Other Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)